# Can't put a css border on this .col-md-10

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border

for some reason I can't seem to get a border around this section of my webpage.

```
.col-md-10 {
background-color: red;
border-radius: 25px;
border-color: gold;
border-width: 20px;
```

}

The border just does not show up.  Why?  Here is the a piece of the HTML file if you need it.  The site won't let me post the whole thing because then it says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add more details."

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en-us">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>About Me</title>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="christmas.css">

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>

 <script src = "portfolio.js"></script>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <style>

    @font-face {
    font-family: Kunstler Script;
    src: url(kunstler.ttf);
}

  #content {
    display: none;
  }

    #time {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  img{
    height: 150px;
  }


  /*Why isn't google developer tools responding to the change I made?*/
  /*Okay, evidently I've got a lot to learn about responsive design.*/
}
</style>

</head>

<body onload = "showStuff(), startSlideshow(), dateNTime(), holidayCheck(), bunnyHop()">


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Dennis Markham</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class = "active"><a href="index.html">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a class = "holiday" href = "#" style="float:right;" onclick = "holiday();">Turn on holiday mode?</a>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id = "content">

<div class ="row">
<div class = "col-md-1"></div>
<div class = "col-md-10">
<img id = "me" src = "images/me1.jpg" alt="my face"></img><h1>About Me</h1><p>Good <span id = "time">afternoon</span> 
  (yes, I know what time it is), sir or madam.  My name is Dennis Markham.  I am <span id = "age">28</span> years old, and a recent graduate of the University
  of Texas Austin Coding Bootcamp.  I also graduated with Certificate in Web Development from Norwalk Community College.  
  I recieved a Bachelor of Science Degree in Psychology from the <a href = "https://uconn.edu/">University of Connecticut</a>.  I am currently
  an instructor for <a href = "https://www.codingwithkids.com/#!/"> Coding With Kids</a>.
  I am looking for a job in web development, preferably front end.  I am particularly fluent in HTML, CSS, Javascript, and 
  JQuery, but also have experience in AngularJS, Node.js, Java, AJAX, SQL, PHP, ES5, ES6, Mongo, Mongoose, and React, as well as substantial 
  experience with softwares/websites such as Sublime, Netbeans, GitBash, GitHub, and SQL Workbench.</p> 
  <p>Signed,</p>
<span style = "font-family: French Script MT; font-size: 3em;">Dennis E. Markham</span> 
</div>
<div class = "col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: border-style was missing, to fix this either use:

```
.col-md-10 {
background-color: red;
border-radius: 25px;
border-color: gold;
border-width: 20px;
border-style: solid;
}
```

or

```
.col-md-10 {
 border: 20px solid gold;
```

Comment: Solved it! Border-style is missing, that'll need to be solid. The default is none. https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_border-style.asp

Comment: I'd also suggest using border: 20px solid gold; rather than the separate ones. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp

Comment: Thanks :)  Didn't need that for my other elements so I wonder why...meh, whatever. Thanks.